# What's a good pattern facade pattern for creating idiomatic Ruby iterators from Java iterators?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I'm using JRuby 1.6.0.RC1. I would like to use the `java.util.Iterators` on some Java libraries more idiomatically from Ruby, by providing a facade implementing a Ruby `each` method.

My first attempt was basically like this:

```
def each_property( myJavaObj )
  i = myJavaObj.myIterator
  while i.hasNext
    yield i.next
  end
end
```

However, when I call `each_property {|p| puts "#{p}"}` I get the error: `LocalJumpError: yield called out of block`.

Can anyone either suggest what I'm doing wrong, or point to a better pattern for invoking Java iterators from Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JRuby has builtin support for turning `java.util.Iterator`s into Ruby `Enumerable`s. So you might also wish to simply do

```
myJavaObj.myIterator.each { ... }
```

in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe calling `yield` inside the `while` block causes this issue.

You may try calling the block explicitly:

```
def each_property(myJavaObj, &block)
  i = myJavaObj.myIterator
  while i.hasNext
    block.call i.next
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Koraktor, that gets my code to run. It would be nice to understand exactly what's going on here though

Comment: `&block` will explicitly tell that your method expects a block and that it will be "converted" into a `Proc` object called `block`. Inside the `while` loop it's called with your parameter - sort of `block(i.next)`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I understand what the &block does; what I'm not sure is why the original `yield` in the context of a `while` block didn't work. Just trying to make sure I understand what went wrong so that I can avoid a similar error in future!